# Fast js datagrid for ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, datagrid

I am looking for js datagrid library for ipad that supports this functionality:

- frozen columns and headers
- Responsive scrolling with about 15 columns and 100 rows

I've already tested a few js libraries like [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) and [Datatables](http://datatables.net/), but they have very bad performance on ipad because they are adopted for desktop use.

What javascript datagrid is good to use on ipads?

Comment: @kyletrauberman could you help me with this question. Why it is not constructive and how can I fix it?

Comment: I dont rememeber if there are some javascript libraries that could solve your problem and no one else does remember on their fingers. try to research on some js libraries, use them in your project and then post the issues or the preoblems you encounter with them. Then you might get some suggestion on how to solve that issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/583894/1626878 . Review it if it is helpfull.